# How can I show a warning before a radiobutton changes in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button

In my flex app I have some radio buttons. When a user clicks the radio button, I want to popup an Alert, and if the user clicks ok the radio button will change, otherwise their change will be discarded.

How do I accomplish that? I tried event.preventDefault(); while handling the click event, but that didn't do anything. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Listen to the `change` event.
- If the new value of `selected` is `true`, set it to `false` and show the popup
- Update the `selected` value based on the result of popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the valueCommit-event and try to stop the behaviour (changing the value) in an event handler. There you can also create a popup...

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event and in your handler do the following:

```
function myHandler(event:MouseEvent) : void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  // statements
}
```

Comment: This doesn't stop the radio button from changing.